# Laravel - How to get posts from db with user data?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to make an instagram clone with PHP laravel.
I want to show posts in home page.

This is the pagesController.php:

```php
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('pages.home', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

And this is the home page view:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post) {
  <div>{{ $post->id }}</div>
  // I want to get the post's owner data.
}
```

And this is the post migration file:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible with laravel eloquent?

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: want to get posts from a logged in user ?

Comment: @Atika I want to get random posts to show in the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and reading the [Laravel Eloquent relationships documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) would be a good place to start. The documentation for Laravel is really very good.

That aside ...

Your migration is incorrect as it is missing the field to store the `user_id` relationship `id`. So you'll want to add that.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteter('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Then in your `User` model, you'll want a function that returns the `Posts` related to the `User`. In this scenario, it is a `hasMany` relationship as a `User` can have `many` `Posts`.

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    // A User has many posts
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Then define the inverse function on the `Post` model to obtain the `User` that it belongs to.

**Post.php**

```
public function User()
{
    // A Post belongs to a single User
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now you have a `migration` and the `relationships` defined on the models, you can go ahead and use them.

Let's assume you have the following route defined (using Laravel 8 syntax).

```
Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
```

Which calls the following `Controller` and `index` function.

**PostController.php**

```
class PostController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Get the Posts and eager load the related User
        $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

In your blade view, you can access the `User` of the `Post` as if it were a property of the `Post`.

**posts/index.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <p>{{ $post->id }}</p>
    <p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

If you want `random` `Posts`, then you can use `inRandomOrder` along with `limit` to get just a few, so for example to get random `10` `Posts`.

```
$posts = Post::inRandomOrder()->with('user')->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `belongsTo` relation in `Post.php` like:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And you could access the user information in blade file like:

```
@foreach($posts as $post) {
  <div>{{ $post->id }}</div>
  // I want to get the post's owner data.
  <h1>{{ $post->user()->get()->name }}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so mush :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a relationship on models.
Just like what is stated above.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

And you can also do eager loading to load relationship on user posts.

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```